# How do I drag an element in Windows 8 XAML app?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

XAML/C# Windows 8 app...

I have used MouseDragElementBehavior in XAML/C# to drag an element around on the screen.

Unfortunately the interactions assembly doesn't work while developing app for Windows 8.

How do I drag an element in Windows 8 XAML app?

Thanks.

**EDIT:** I found a sample example here: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Input-3dff271b/sourcecode?fileId=44758&pathId=962809525

Just copy the code and am able to drag my element. Having some issues will update, if need help.

Comment: Do you want to drag & drop items from a GridView/ListView or just any other control ? The way to achieve it is way more easy in the first case.

Comment: @RenaudDumont it's not listview, it's just an item say an icon image on the page that user can drag anywhere on the page. And then I what i want is when the user lifts the finger/mouse and release the element, it should animate and return to it's original position.

Answer (score 2):

You need to handle the manipulation events on the element you wish to drag. And also, set ManipulationMode to a value other than None on the element.

1. Handle `ManipulationStarted` to initialize your drag code
2. Handle `ManipulationDelta`, inspecting the `e.Delta` values, and offset your element using a `RenderTransform`, or if in a `Canvas`, use the canvas coordinates.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a overly simplified example based on ColinE's answer.

Consider a Canvas that has an ellipse:

```
<Canvas Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Ellipse Fill="Red" 
             Canvas.Left="100"
             Canvas.Top="100"
             Width="100" 
             Height="100" 
             ManipulationMode="All" 
             ManipulationDelta="Ellipse_ManipulationDelta_1"/>
</Canvas>
```

Now in the code behind, you handle the ManipulationDelta:

```
private void Ellipse_ManipulationDelta_1(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Ellipse myEllipse = (Ellipse)sender;
        Canvas.SetLeft(myEllipse, Canvas.GetLeft(myEllipse) + e.Delta.Translation.X);
        Canvas.SetTop(myEllipse, Canvas.GetTop(myEllipse) + e.Delta.Translation.Y);
    }
```

Comment: Used this more generic solution: http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.com/2012/04/porting-dragflickbehavior-from-windows.html