# How to build Pentomino game

Tags: c#, windows, xaml

I want to build the Pentomino game in C#/XAML for Windows 8(8.1). I need field and draggable figures.

How I can do it? For draggable I'm using ManipulationDelta property, but how do I know that the figure is in the field and how do I attach it (figure in field)?

Comment: What have you tried? What have you read? What are you thinking about doing it?

Comment: I try use for figures images and rectangles. For image I cant set clear borders for each figure. So with rectangle I can use only.. rectangle. Now I try combine rectangles to figure (2x2 now) and drag all of it if drag anyone. 
But about field.. I dont have ideas about it. Now I try to use Grid (Columns and Rows), but have one general question: how can I know where is figure after move? In which cells (columns/rows)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your question stands, it's too broad.

For future reference, you should try splitting your problem into smaller problems, and asking seprate questions for each of them after doing some home research first.

Also, sharing some code about what you've tried can get more people to help you.

---

Having said that, I've never worked with XAML, though I've worked with C# for some time now.

About your problems:

For pentomino you will need a board. using `Grid` or `DataGridView` sounds like a good approch to me.

For representing your figures, your grid can be queried to find out if your figure can be droped on a certain square. Prepare for writing some `for` loops.

Abput drag'n drop, here are some links that you may find useful:

[XAML GridView to GridView Drag and Drop Mouse vs Touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16483739/xaml-gridview-to-gridview-drag-and-drop-mouse-vs-touch)

[Dropping an item on an UserControl item in GridView doesnt trigger Drop event (includes sample project)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038379/dropping-an-item-on-an-usercontrol-item-in-gridview-doesnt-trigger-drop-event-i?rq=1)

[How do I drag an element in Windows 8 XAML app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12633512/how-do-i-drag-an-element-in-windows-8-xaml-app)